# Puppet: could not retrieve catalog from remote server

Tags: ssl, puppet

Running `sudo puppet agent -t` from host: host.internaltest.com

`err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Another local       or imported resource exists with the type and title Host[host.internaltest.com] on node host.internaltest.com`

This machine had its ssl certs messed with so I cleaned it off the master and then using autosign (bad bad i know!) I ran `sudo puppet agent -t` which regenerated the ssl cert but also threw this error. Let me know if you need more information, I haven't delete with this aspect of puppet too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely `puppetmaster` has this cert in the memory. You need to clean the cert both on client and in the master

```
#On client machine do this assuming puppet libdir = /var/lib/puppet

rm -rf /var/lib/puppet/ssl/*/*.pem

#On the puppet-master

puppet cert clean host.internaltest.com

# Restart puppet-master

/sbin/service puppetmasterd restart

# If you are using puppet-master behind passenger, you may need to restart httpd

/sbin/service httpd restart

# then run puppet agent on the client to regenerate the cert
```

Answer (score 2):

If one uses an stunnel and globally set http_proxy this error will occur when it is redirected to the wrong endpoint.